# PowerShell change datatypes of the Data.DataTable object

Tags: powershell, csv, datatable

I am working on a script which creates a `Data.DataTable` with the data from a .csv file. Everything worked fine, I have it in my database with the right values. But to help my database performance I would like to set the data types for the columns of the `Data.DataTable`. Unfortunately all my values are converted to strings from the CSV to the `Data.DataTable` columns.

My CSV looks like this (example):

```
"Name";"UserID";"Salary"
"Peter";"1";"1200.03"
"Jennifer";"2";"1000.50"
```

I tried following methods:

```
foreach ($object in $csv){
    Write-Output "line $countline"

    foreach($property in $object.PsObject.get_properties()) 
        {   
        $property.TypeNameOfValue = [System.Type]::'System.Int32'

          ***and the other try*** 

        $property.Value = [System.Type]::'System.Int32'
        }
    }
```

Both times nothing happened (except errors).

So I want the following to happen: The first column should be a datatype of string ("name"). The others should be double or float.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this dilemma. I will say, `Import-CSV` has some limitations if you want to work with anything other than strings, but it can be done.

Method 1: [Hash Tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx)

```
$data = import-csv .\data.csv -Delimiter ';'
$hashtable = [ordered]@{"Name" = ($data).name; "UserID" = ($data).UserID.ToDouble($_); "Salary" = ($data).Salary.ToDouble($_)}
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\> $hashtable.Name
Peter
Jennifer
PS C:\> $hashtable.Name | GM
TypeName: System.String
PS C:\> $hashtable.UserID
1
2
PS C:\> $hashtable.UserID | GM
TypeName: System.Double
```

Method 2: [CSV Files with Type Information](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/09/23/use-powershell-to-work-with-csv-formatted-text.aspx)

This method is a little easier to use the traditional way I'm used to `Import-Csv` but I couldn't combine the results into a single variable. Not the end of the world, but also a little more work to make more CSV files and figure out how to apply a type to them.

Example CSV files:

```
#TYPE System.String
"Name"
"Peter"
"Jennifer"
```

And

```
#TYPE System.Double
"UserID";"Salary"
"1";"1200.03"
"2";"1000.50"
```

Example results from using `Import-Csv`:

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\double.csv -Delimiter ';'
UserID Salary
------ ------
1      1200.03
2      1000.50
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\double.csv -Delimiter ';' | GM
TypeName: CSV:System.Double
```

Optional Method: If you're feeling brave, someone who wrote proxy script for `Import-Csv` over here: [Importing typed objects with typed properties from a CSV file](http://poshoholic.com/2009/09/18/powershell-3-0-why-wait-importing-typed-objects-with-typed-properties-from-a-csv-file/), but I did not test that myself. I mention it because it looks like a good way to deal with this if it comes up frequently.

I found this article on how to deal with some of the [quirks of hash tables](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/16/dealing-with-powershell-hash-table-quirks.aspx) to be helpful.