# Unable to convert string to date type using Import-Csv

Tags: sql-server, string, powershell, csv, date

For my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252209/insert-data-row-wise-in-a-sql-table-from-a-csv-using-powershell) question, I implemented the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405575/how-to-insert-data-of-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-db-table-using-powershell) SO link. I used the **.NET** libraries and used the two functions [Out-DataTable](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd) and [Write-DataTable](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae) in my solution.

Currently, I have my `CSVs` in place and using the `Out-DataTable` and `Write-DataTable` functions to insert data into SQL Server. However, it is not working with `date` data types. I get the error -

> Write-DataTable :
>   System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception
>   calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "The given value of type
>   String from the data source cannot be converted to type date of the
>   specified target column." --->
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to
>   type date of the specified target column. ---> System.FormatException:
>   Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime. --->
>   System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>   DateTimeStyles styles)    at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value,
>   IFormatProvider provider)    at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object
>   value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType
>   destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged,
>   Boolean allowStreaming)

So when I looked into `Out-DataTable` function, it has another function named `Get-Type` defined in it, which basically does the column type conversion. Here is the function `Get-Type` -

```
function Get-Type 
{ 
    param($type) 

$types = @( 
'System.Boolean', 
'System.Byte[]', 
'System.Byte', 
'System.Char', 
'System.Datetime', 
'System.Decimal', 
'System.Double', 
'System.Guid', 
'System.Int16', 
'System.Int32', 
'System.Int64', 
'System.Single', 
'System.UInt16', 
'System.UInt32', 
'System.UInt64') 

    if ( $types -contains $type ) { 
        Write-Output "$type" 
    } 
    else { 
        Write-Output 'System.String' 

    } 
} #Get-Type
```

Now SQL has a data type as [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) other than the **.NET's** `datetime` function. Hence, I am running into this error.

I had a thought of using `parseexact` method, but that again doesn't resolve the issue, since it resolves to type `string`. Also, `Import-Csv` takes in a flat file, hence the date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` will always be of type `string` and my code would fail inevitably.

I have looked for a solution at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4eylez/converting_sql_data_types_to_system_data_types/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678365/powershell-change-datatypes-of-the-data-datatable-object) link, but I am not able to figure it out how to convert the string type into date. Any help will be much appreciated. Also, let me know if any extra info is required.

Comment: `parseexact`  returns a datetime (at least a .net one)? So you could use that in a select statement as a caculated property to pass down the pipeline. I am unsure why that did not work for you. `[datetime]::ParseExact(((date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),"yyyy-MM-dd",$null)` note the $null is in the culture placeholder so that might be significant depending on your local

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over data until it is exported as a `CSV`. So nothing much working out from `SQL` side of things. I was hoping if anything could be done from `PoSh` end. `Import-Csv` takes in the data from a flat file and converts the unresolved type to `String`. Much appreciated @Matt!

Comment: But you have control to import the data yes before it is converted to a datatable? or is the csv import part of `write-tabledata`

Comment: @Matt - The data before the import comes from `Invoke-SqlCmd` command, the output of which is of type `array`. But I get what you are implying. There are other ways of invoking a `SQL` query the output of which will be of type `datatable`. I will try and let you know. Thanks for the pro-tip.

Comment: @Matt - It worked. Thanks a ton for the wonderful tip. I had so many things in my mind and so many things to look at that the thought of directly inserting from a PowerShell variable of type `array/datatable` didn't cross my mind. `Invoke-Sqlcmd's` result, when stored in a variable will preserve the table structure and it can directly be use with the aforementioned `Write-DataTable` function.