# The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type uniqueidentifier of the specified target column

Tags: sql-server, string, powershell, datatable, uniqueidentifier

What I'm trying here is, to load the data from .xml file to the SQL server database using PowerShell Script.

My Script goes like:

```
$dataSource = 'dtsrc';                                       
$database = 'tempdb';   #DB

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;  #setting connection
$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$dataSource;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;";
$connection.Open();

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$command.Connection = $connection;

$as = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$as.SelectCommand = $command;
$filename = 'C:\DCT\XML\apc.xml';            #file to be loaded into sql server database table

$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$ds.ReadXml($filename);    #reading from the file -- line gives output InferSchema

$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;

$dt.Columns.Add("StartTime",[datetime]);
$dt.Columns.Add("EndTime",[datetime]);
$dt.Columns.Add("Status",[int]);
$dt.Columns.Add("ProcessedTime",[datetime]);
$dt.Columns.Add("ScheduleId",[guid]);
$dt.Columns.Add("Model",[string]);
$dt.Columns.Add("ModelVersion",[string]);
$dt.Columns.Add("ModelVersionState",[string]);
$dt.Columns.Add("ModifiedTime",[datetime]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("WriteBackLastRunTime",[datetime]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("ModifiedBy",[string]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("ModelType",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("IsTimeRange",[int]);#b
 $dt.Columns.Add("WriteBackStatus",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("RetryWriteBack",[int]);#b
 $dt.Columns.Add("NumOfRetry",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("FrequencyUnits",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("ScheduleType",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("CustomType",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("ShiftStartTime",[datetime]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("StartWeekDay",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("EndWeekDay",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("WritebackProcessedTime",[datetime]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("DiagStatus",[int]);
 $dt.Columns.Add("AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID",[guid]);

 $dt = $ds.Tables[0];

$bcp = New-Object 'Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy' $connection; #bulkcopy to the destination table.
$bcp.DestinationTableName = 'dbo.tempor';

#$bcp.ColumnMappings.Count;
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Clear();

$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('StartTime','StartTime');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('EndTime','EndTime');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('Status','Status');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ProcessedTime','ProcessedTime');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ScheduleId','ScheduleId');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('Model','Model');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ModelVersion','ModelVersion');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ModelVersionState','ModelVersionState');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ModifiedTime','ModifiedTime');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('WriteBackLastRunTime','WriteBackLastRunTime');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ModifiedBy','ModifiedBy');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ModelType','ModelType');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('IsTimeRange','IsTimeRange');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('WriteBackStatus','WriteBackStatus');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('RetryWriteBack','RetryWriteBack');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('NumOfRetry','NumOfRetry');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('FrequencyUnits','FrequencyUnits');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ScheduleType','ScheduleType');
#$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('CustomType','CustomType');
#$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('ShiftStartTime','ShiftStartTime');
#$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('StartWeekDay','StartWeekDay');
#$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('EndWeekDay','EndWeekDay');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('WritebackProcessedTime','WritebackProcessedTime');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('DiagStatus','DiagStatus');
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add('AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID','AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID');    

if ($connection.State -ne [Data.ConnectionState]::Open) {

    'Connection to DB is not open.'

    Exit

}

$bcp.WriteToServer($dt);        #writing to server 
$connection.Close();
```

The error I'm facing is:

```
Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type uniqueidentifier of the specified target column." At C:\Documents\DCT\SavedScripts\XMLtoDB\AccountingPeriodCases\sample.ps1:91 char:1
+ $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);        #writing to server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

and the table I created has the columns with datatypes:

[image]

The thing is, I guess i need to convert the String that is in the datatable under the column ScheduleId and AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID as they are not getting converted to uniqueidentifier.

I tried using 
`[System.Guid]::Parse($dt.Columns[4]);`
`[System.Guid]::Parse($dt.Columns[24]);`

but the error repeats.

The xml content to be loaded under thr ScheduleId and AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID looks like:

```
<ScheduleId>db6f3178-4702-456c-904b-2cd833b54efa</ScheduleId>
<AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>9544940d-8d1a-e711-80d3-0050569c2fb6</AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>
```

Could anyone help me resolve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: What format are the strings that are failing?  They should look like a typical GUID (e.g. `39FD3A0E-B4F2-4969-863D-A790ED7F72E5`).  If the string is empty, you should supply the empty GUID instead (e.g. `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`)

Comment: I faced a similar situation. See that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275994/unable-to-convert-string-to-date-type-using-import-csv). Might work for you with a few tweaks.

Comment: @boxdog i have added a sample of what the sample info to be loaded looks like.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I will gave it a try though, but the error still prevails.. also im quite new to this area, just started working with scripts so not much familiar with stuff, please do help me if i have gone wrong or missed any point anywhere.. Thank you for the response though... I will try reading it again thoroughly and giving it a try...

Comment: The thing is if you are reading from an XML file, then you are bound to get an error, because while reading from a flat-file(txt, csv) or an XML, PowerShell will resolve the undefined types to `String`. The trick is to have some sort of control over the source. If your source is a PowerShell variable such as `datatable` or an `array`, then you can directly insert values from this variable to your destination table. This is the approach which I followed. In my case, the source was a result of the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` which preserved the original data types and hence made insertion error less.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh thank you so much.. it works.. i made a big mistake... i took column to parse instead of the row values, now it works... thank you

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh, consider adding your comment as an answer, so it's more visible to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275994/unable-to-convert-string-to-date-type-using-import-csv), which I had faced earlier, it comes down to the source of your input.

The thing is if you are reading from an `XML` file, then you are bound to get an error, because while reading from a `flat-file(txt, csv)` or an `XML`, `PowerShell` will resolve the undefined types to String. The trick is to have some sort of control over the source. If your source is a `PowerShell` variable such as `datatable` or an `array`, then you can directly insert values from this variable to your destination table, since the original data types of the columns in a table are preserved.

This is the approach which I followed. In my case, the source was a result of the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` which preserved the original data types and hence made insertion error less.

Again as mentioned in the comment by OP, he was parsing values based on `columns` and not `rows`. This could also lead to an error. For example, there is one more way of inserting values in a table which is using the `INSERT` statement. Mind you that, the `SQL Server` `INSERT` statement inserts value on a row-level and not a column level. In such a scenario, parsing the values `column` wise may fail.